# Post to wall without a shareDialog() SDK4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I can post to Facebook using their sharDialog() pop-up. However, if I want to post a set message on a button click, without having the dialog pop up,  how do I go about doing that?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  ShareDialog share;
    private ShareLinkContent content;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().setContentTitle("CURRENT LOCATION").build();

        share = new ShareDialog(this);

        ImageButton fbBut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
        fbBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                share.show(content);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            //Opens the settings preferences
            Intent settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(settings);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }
}
```

This is the code that I have so far.